Exception with Jackson-Module-Jaxb-Annotation when upgrading to Jakarta EE
i am trying to upgrade my application from JEE 8 to Jakarta EE.
When I am starting the application, it is throwing this exception

with Jackson-Module-Jaxb-Annotations-2.17.1 trying to use the old javax.xml.bind classes rather than the jakarta.xml.bind classes that the application now has (I am using jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.2)
I would expect the most recent version of the jars to be using the jakarta version of the bind classes
When I look at the maven repository for Jackson-Module-Jaxb-Annotations 2.17.1 it lists 3.0.1 as the appropriate version of jakarta.xml.bind-api but that doesn't have javax.xml.bind classes in it either so I am wondering what I am doing wrong here and how I can get around this problem.
Happy to provide additional information if required

According to the stack trace in the image (please, next time just copy paste it instead of screenshotting it, so that fellow sufferers can at least find the same exception using a search engine), you're using Tomcat not a full JEE server. And, JAXB has been removed from Java SE since version 9. So, if you also upgraded Java SE to 9 or newer while keeping using Tomcat instead of a full JEE server, you'll need to manually install JAXB via webapp (because Tomcat doesn't provide JAXB out the box while a full JEE server does). Alternative is to replace Tomcat by a full JEE server.

@BalusC would install JAXB via webapp be achieved by downloading the jaxb runtime in maven so if I add this to my pom

org.glassfish.jaxb
jaxb-runtime
4.0.5


You should use the following module
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>

It's mainly the same thing as the jackson-module-jaxb-annotations but for jakarta xml (so for jaxb 3 and upper versions)

I already have that in my pom the problem appeared to be the lack of the javax .xml files - I ended up getting around this issue by adding those using                                                                                                                       javax.xml.bindjaxb-api2.3.1                                           Apologies I don't seem able to add images to my answers

Adding jaxb-api 2.3.1 will add back javax-based JAXB which shouldn't be done if migrating to Jakarta EE.

are you saying that I should just remove jackson-module-jaxb-annotations and only have the jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations in my pom?

If you plan to move to Jakarta, I'd say yes :)
